# Perl script fails to run Schedule task with "%1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: perl, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a Perl script in Windows 2012 R2 (64 bit) using schedule task.
I am getting `%1 is not a valid Win32 application. (0x800700C1)` error. When I run this script from the command prompt it runs fine

I have Strawberry Perl (64 bit) installed on this server.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: it's possible that your PATH is not set in the scheduled task's environment. Are you supplying the full path to the perl.exe binary in the command, or do you just have `perl script.pl`?

Comment: `%1` should normally be substituted by the value of the first parameter to a .bat file. It sounds like a command that should be processed by the shell is being run directly. What is the chain of activation? Does the scheduler run a .bat file, or a Perl program?

Comment: @Borodin... the scheduler runs the perl program (absolute path)...

Comment: @syedf: So where is this `%1`? there must be a .bat file involved somewhere. Something the Perl program is trying to run?

Comment: There is no .bat file involved. It is a plain perl script. This script was working with schedule task when I had Active Perl 5.22 installed. I un-installed it and installed Strawberry perl and since then the Schedule task does not work.

Comment: Ok ... I got it... The issue was in the "Action" tab of Schedule task, I was just adding the perl script to run without using any "perl" executable. It worked with Active perl but after installing Strawberry version, it was not working.....So now I added this to the "Program/script" box: "perl C:\full\path\to\script.pl" and it worked.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It guided me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Windows OS you're using, for Windows 7 professional, One need to add the full path to perl exe in the "program/script" box, and the full path to the perl script in the "Add Arguments (optional)" box. I had the same problem, this fixed the problem.